# select timestamp from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a problem with query where the conditions are related to **TIMESTAMP** column. So I have a table named **table1** which has two columns `start_time` and `end_time`. Both of them store **TIMESTAMP**. I want to query my databse for a particular rows where `end_time` is higher than given timestamp value and lower than given timestamp value. Basically I want to get all the rows where `end_time` is between given **TIMESTAMP** range.

I have found that in my case following query works:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) >= FROM_UNIXTIME('2015-11-30 20:14:00') 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) <= FROM_UNIXTIME('2015-11-30 20:14:05')
```

But it is not what I want to. I want to give **TIMESTAMP** value instead of **DATE**.

What is also strange is that this query returns values that have `end_time` of earlier date than given timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE end_time > FROM_UNIXTIME( '2015-11-30 20:20:05' )
```

Query above returns rows where `end_timestamp` is **2015-11-30 20:18:05**

I feel that I am missing something here. Should I use **INT** instead of **TIMESTAMP** for my `end_time`? I believe that the following query should return expected values but it gives me nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE end_time >= FROM_UNIXTIME( 1448914740 ) 
AND end_time <= FROM_UNIXTIME( 1448914810 )
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert your `WHERE` clause values using `FROM_UNIXTIME`. `FROM_UNIXTIME` converts a TIMESTAMP into a date. If you're sending values to the SQL statement that are already in `TIMESTAMP` format, your `SQL` will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE end_time >= 1448914740 AND end_time <= 1448914810
```

If you are sending date strings (e.g. '2015-11-30 20:14:00' and '2015-11-30 20:14:05') then your `SQL` would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time) >= '2015-11-30 20:14:00' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time) <= '2015-11-30 20:14:05'
```

Since you're storing your values in your table as `TIMESTAMP` I would recommend you use the first `SQL` statement.